# mysql column import to php script (temporarily)

Tags: php, mysql

how to import data (column) into a php script temporarily (php script is read only)

let me explain

I have a php file which contain something like this

```
$playerData['players'][] = 'player1';
$playerData['players'][] = 'player2';
$playerData['players'][] = 'player3';
$playerData['players'][] = 'player4';
```

and the list goes on
the problem is php script is getting bigger and everytime I need to add a player, I have to modify php script.

Is there any way so it can be like this

```
$playerData['players'][]        = $playername;
```

where $playername contains player1 then repeat the step now $playername contains player2 and so on till the last entry (a loop) in column so it can be like

```
$playerData['players'][] = 'player1';
$playerData['players'][] = 'player2';
$playerData['players'][] = 'player3';
$playerData['players'][] = 'player4';
$playerData['players'][] = 'player5';
$playerData['players'][] = 'player6';
$playerData['players'][] = 'player7';
$playerData['players'][] = 'player8';
```

and so on.....

but php script should not be modified, it should stay intact, means all of this should happen in the RAM (or anything) WITHOUT modifying php script.

Comment: why can't the script be modified? If you need to add new players every time you load that file, then those players SHOULD go into the file, so you don't have to waste code adding them to the list every time. This is something for which a database would be perfect.

Comment: database * million - thats all

Comment: Imagine once you'll need to edit right up to `$playerData['players'][] = 'player43988';` ? As `Marc B` stated, the use of a DB would be the way to go using a unique `ID` as a primary key, plus emailing each member would be a cinch, if ever an option were something you think you might like to use, or block someone etc.